# Adding properties to ApplicationContext from a TestExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I'm setting up an integration test for my Spring Boot (1.3.1) application. At context startup my application reads its state from a data directory, which in production is provided in application.properties:

```
datadir.location=<path to directory>
```

Now, if I just wanted to use a fixed directory in my test, I could use @TestPropertySource like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"datadir.location=<path to test data directory>"})
public class MyIntegrationTest {
}
```

However, I want to generate the test data in the test, so I set up a TestExecutionListener to create a temporary directory and add the test data. The test now looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest({"server.port=0", "management.port=0"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DataDirSetupListener.class}, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    public void initDataDirectory(Path pathToDataDir) {
        // Setup of contents in temporary data directory goes here
    }
}
```

The TestExecutionListener looks like this:

```
public class DataDirSetupListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {
        Path tempDataDir = Files.createTempDirectory("datadir");

        // This call asks testContext for the test class, and
        // calls the initDataDirectory method
        findAndCallInitDataDirectory(tempDataDir);

        // TODO: Set datadir.location = tempDataDir.toString();
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

So, the listener runs fine and create the data directory before the ApplicationContext is brought up, but what is the proper way to provide the location of the data directory to the context?

(If moving the datadir setup to prepareTestInstance instead of beforeTestClass would facilitate things, that's fine.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring profiles. So in test run profile test and define diffrent application properties to every profile

```
application-{profile}.properties
```

[Spring profile application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Look on seciton 24.4

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply this to my situation, as the property value is not known until the code in DataDirSetupListener has run.

Comment: How the data is populated to this DataDirSetupListener ?

Comment: I updated the original post. The listener asks the TestContext for the current test class, and uses that to call the initDataDirectory method in the test class.